# Version of debian 9.5 is not correct

Tags: debian

I downloaded and tried to install Debian 9.5 from this page:

http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/9.5.0/

After completing installing, I checked the version by the command "lsb_release -da".

The result is Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch).

I think that it should be 9.5 (stretch)

Do you know what thing wrong?

Comment: During installation the installer asks you if you want to use a network mirror. If you say yes, it will load packages from the network mirror after the tasksel selection screen.

Comment: Your information resolved my problem. Thank you very much @cronoik.